# Convert string values ​to int (esp32)

Tags: javascript, html, esp32

I'm trying to program a web server on an esp32, with which I want to control a WS2812b LED strip. I am just about to just display colors and would like to solve this using the GET method. If I read the values ​​as a string, it all works, but when I try to convert them to int, I get strange output in the serial monitor.
I tried the string.toInt () function and also typecast.

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <ESPmDNS.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define PIN 2
#define NUM 150

const char* ssid = "WLAN";
const char* password = "...";

String html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"><link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\"><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css\"><script src=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js\"></script></head><body><div class=\"container\"><div class=\"row\"><h1>ESP Color Picker</h1></div><a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-lg\" href=\"#\" id=\"change_color\" role=\"button\">Change Color</a><input class=\"jscolor {onFineChange:'update(this)'}\" id=\"rgb\"></div><script>function update(picker) {document.getElementById('rgb').innerHTML = Math.round(picker.rgb[0]) + ', ' +  Math.round(picker.rgb[1]) + ', ' + Math.round(picker.rgb[2]);document.getElementById(\"change_color\").href=\"?r=\" + Math.round(picker.rgb[0]) + \"&g=\" +  Math.round(picker.rgb[1]) + \"&b=\" + Math.round(picker.rgb[2]) + \"&\";}</script></body></html>";
            
AsyncWebServer server(80);
Adafruit_NeoPixel stripe (NUM, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
 
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
      stripe.setPixelColor(0,stripe.Color(0,0,0));
    }
  stripe.show();
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Verbinde mit WLAN...");
  }
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  if(!MDNS.begin("ledStripe_1"))
    {
      Serial.println("Fehler beim DNS");
      return;
    }
 
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){

    String s_rot, s_gruen, s_blau;
    int paramsNr = request->params();
    Serial.print("Anzahl der Parameter: ");
    Serial.println(paramsNr);
 
    for(int i=0;i<paramsNr;i++){
 
        AsyncWebParameter* p = request->getParam(i);
        Serial.print("Parametername: ");
        Serial.println(p->name());
        Serial.print("Parameterwert: ");
        Serial.println(p->value());
        Serial.println("------");

        if(i == 0)
        {
          s_rot = String(p->value());
        }
        else if(i == 1)
        {
          s_gruen =  String(p->value());
        }
        else if(i == 2)
        {
          s_blau =  String(p->value());
        }
    }

    Serial.println("Rot: " + s_rot);
    Serial.println("Grün: " + s_gruen);
    Serial.println("Blau: " + s_blau + "\n");

    int rot = (int)s_rot;
    
    Serial.println("Rot: " + rot);
//    Serial.println("Grün: " + gruen);
//    Serial.println("Blau: " + blau);

//    stripe.setPixelColor(0,stripe.Color((int)rot, (int)gruen, (int)blau));
//    stripe.show();
 
    request->send(200, "text/html", html);
  });
 
  server.begin();
}
 
void loop(){}
```

Comment: Did you try [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)?

Comment: This looks like C or C++ code, why is it tagged javascript?

Comment: ... ?r=\" + Math.round(picker.rgb[0]) + ... there? so ... ?r=\" + parseInt(Math.round(picker.rgb[0])) + ...

Comment: cause the colorpicker by String html ...